# Появление нового элемента при скроле вниз

Tags: android

Добрый день. Есть ToolBar и какой-то список, например Recycler View. Хочу реализовать: при вертикальном движении пальца ВНИЗ по списку, этот список отодвигается на высоту одного элемента списка, как используется в приложениях Instagram(скрин ниже) и Twitter, но в моём случае должен  зафиксироваться на этом месте. В свободном месте появляется окно EditText. При обратном движении пальца по списку(ВВЕРХ), список выезжает вверх и упирается в ToolBar(возвращается в дефолтное состояние), а окно EditText исчезает.
Пробовал использовать `swipeRefreshLayout`, но при свайпе вниз, он всегда возвращается в дефолтное состоянии без участия пользователя.

Посоветуйте в каком направлении думать, потратил уже 2 дня, но никаких идей решения этой задачи не нашел.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE:** Я отлавливаю движение пальцем вниз способом, описанным в этой статье [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)

И программно отодвигаю список Recycler View вниз, а поле EditText(которое было по умолчанию invisible) делаю видимым. Но тут возникает другая проблема: чтение отклика происходит в любых местах экрана, даже там где не нужно.
Может кто знает другое решение этой задачи?

Comment: сделайте float footer с размером item вашего списка. отследите scroll. если скролл вниз, футер выезжает(можно анимировать), если вверх то прячется. На мой взгляд проще и красивей будет.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei я более правильно обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поставил сколллисенер на список

```
RecyclerView r = new RecyclerView(ctx);
  r.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
      super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    }
  });
```

А экран бы построил таким образом:
[Тулбар]
[Список]
[............]
[............]
[............]
[............]
[Подвал]

По деволту подвал имеет высоту 0

И стал бы считать, на сколько я прокрутил список вниз. В определенный момент, например, при прокрутке на 50 пикселей, я запустил бы код, который с помощью какой-нибудь ease-функции увеличит высоту подвала на определенное значение. В подвале же будет размещен поиск

Comment: интересная идея, но как  подвал переместить на вверх, между тулбаром и RecyclerView?

Comment: Из вопроса не было понятно, что поиск должен оказаться между тулбаром и подвалом. В таком случае просто поместите в LinearLayout последовательно тулбар, поиск(с дефолтной высотой 0) и список

Comment: я обновил вопрос и добавил пояснительную картинку, посмотрите пожалуйста